Terragrunt and outputs, when creating mssql database
modules/tf-sqlserver-module/main.tf:
resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "sqlserver" {
  administrator_login = var.admin_username
  administrator_login_password = var.admin_pw
  name                = local.sql_full_name
  resource_group_name = var.rg_sql_name
  location            = var.location
  version             = "12.0"  # Choose the desired SQL Server version
  azuread_administrator {
    login_username    = var.azure_ad_admin_user
    object_id         = var.azure_ad_object_id
  }
  tags = {
    project           = "${var.project_tag}"
    environment       = "${var.environment_tag}"
  }
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

modules/tf-sqlserver-module/outputs.tf:
output "sql_server_id" {
  description = "ID of the created Azure SQL Server"
  value       = azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver.id
}

output "sql_server_fqdn" {
  description = "Fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of the SQL Server"
  value       = azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver.fully_qualified_domain_name
}

output "azure_ad_admin_user" {
  description = "Azure AD Admin User Principal Name"
  value       = var.azure_ad_admin_user
}


modules/tf-sqlserver-module/variables.tf containing all variables needed.
in sqldb-dev/terragrunt.hcl
...
dependency "sql_srv" {
  config_path = "../sqlserver-dev"
  mock_outputs = {
    sql_server_id = "tempid"
  }
}

inputs = {
  db_prefix = local.db_prefix
  location = local.location
  collation = local.collation
  project_tag = local.project
  environment_tag = local.environment
  sql_server_id = dependency.sql_srv.outputs.sql_server_id
  branch = "dev"
}

sqlserver-dev/terragrunt.hcl:
I get this error for the database
Unsupported attribute; This object does not have an attribute named "sql_server_id".
I am tryeing to create a environment interragrunt. The expected output should be that the sqldb gets teh outout from the module.

Instead of referencing it from dependency block, can you try referencing it directly from the terraform main.tf  output  block. @Faux_Clef

How do i do that?

I solved this problem by adding a data block to the variables.tf file:
data "azurerm_mssql_server" "sqlserver" {
  resource_group_name = var.rg_sql_name
  name = local.sql_full_name
}

The outputs.tf will have get the data by :
output "server_id" {
  description = "ID of the created Azure SQL Server"
  value       = data.azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver.id
}


Your config_path should be ../modules/tf-sqlserver-module.
...
dependency "sql_srv" {
  config_path = "../modules/tf-sqlserver-module"
  mock_outputs = {
    sql_server_id = "tempid"
  }
}

inputs = {
  db_prefix = local.db_prefix
  location = local.location
  collation = local.collation
  project_tag = local.project
  environment_tag = local.environment
  sql_server_id = dependency.sql_srv.outputs.sql_server_id
  branch = "dev"
}


This is wrong, my terraform modules are just terraform and does not contain a terragrunt.hcl:
time=2024-05-08T12:57:58+02:00 level=error msg=Error .
…
./modules/tf-sqlserver-module/terragrunt.hcl: The system cannot find the file specified.
time=2024-05-08T12:57:58+02:00 level=error msg=Unable to determine underlying exit code, so Terragrunt will exit with error code 1


